# change content on resize without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, shieldui

I'm using ShieldUI's "Tabs" and there is a property for the tabs position. I want when the screen width is >= 768px to display the tabs at "left" and while <= 768px to display them on the "top". I came to here:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $pane = $('#tabsDiv');

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 768) {
        $pane.shieldTabs({
            position: "top"
        });
    } else {
        $pane.shieldTabs({
            position: "left"
        });
    }
}

checkWidth();

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

But when i'm full width and i go "mobile" i have to refresh the page to get what i want, is there a way to do that without page refresh?

Comment: Provide a working example that demonstrates the problem (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet).

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kiribot/edit?output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We kind of have some issues with your code, along with the `Shield UI` limitations. Let's see some of them:

- First of all, for what I've checked at the [official docs](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/tabs/javascript/api/methods), the framework does support component refreshing, but only [for new options you'd like to add to your widgets](https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite/blob/master/common/core.js#L769). Therefore, your code won't work when you try to update specific features of the tab (like the `position`). This means that it's good to have a global function (`initTabs`, in our case) for destroying and recreating the whole tab structure;
- Second, once you do that, don't declare the resizing function inside of this global new one, in order to evict recursiveness problems;
- It's also a good idea creating a global variable to store the state of the tabs position, since we have now local/global functions to handle.

Check out the final working code: https://jsfiddle.net/ro0a5bhv/4/

***Note:*** See that I had to do a workaround regarding the CSS property `min-height`, which is always set by the framework when switching tab views.

Comment: You can use .refresh() on all Shield UI plugin instances to refresh any component. It should be a base method. You can also pass a subset of properly arranged options dictionary, which you want to be merged with the original properties, thus overriding them.

Comment: @VladimirGeorgiev, to refresh any component is not what the docs say about it. The only `.refresh()` function available there is for Grid widgets (https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/refresh). Straight to Tabs API demo (https://demos.shieldui.com/web/tabs/api), even them use the *destroy/recreate* strategy... Do you have any functional code to comprove/enrich this points?

Comment: As far as I know, the .refresh() method is implemented for all widgets, but is not fully documented... Here you can see it is in the base shield ui widget class: https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite/blob/master/common/core.js#L769

Comment: You're right, there is a refresh for Widget objects, but it seems to be restricted to only add new options, not update any already added (which wouldn't work for this situation..). Thanks @VladimirGeorgiev!

Comment: AFAIK, the code uses $.extend, which will override the old options with any new ones passed.